# How to store text and post in above rows in specific column if condition is met?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a code to look for a specific keyword ("Team") and when found I want to paste the team name in a specific column ("D") for all rows above. If the keyword is not found I want to copy the entire row. This all pasted into a new sheet.

What I have:

x-------------x------------x

x-------------x------------x

Team A----x------------x

x-------------x-------------x

x-------------x-------------x

Team B----x-------------x

What I want:

x----x----x----A

x----x----x----A

x----x----x----B

x----x----x----B

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub fun()
  Dim j as Integer
  Dim lastrow as Integer
  Dim team as String
  Dim sh As Worksheet

  sh = Sheets("Sheet 1")
  lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlup).Row
  Range("A" & lastrow).Select

  for j = 1 to lastrow

    If Instr(Cells(j,1).Value, "Team") Then
        Cells(j,1).Value = Replace(Cells(j,1).Value, "Team ", "")
        Cells(j,1).Value = team
    Else
        Range(Cells(j,1), Cells(j,3). Select
        Selection.Copy

        Windows("sheet.xlsm").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=False
    End If

  next j

End Sub
```

I'm able to meet the second condition and paste entire rows but I'm unsure how to copy the team names and post them in column D in the new sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub fun()

  Dim j As Long, destRow As Long
  Dim team As String, v, rngTeam As Range
  Dim sh As Worksheet, shDest As Worksheet

  Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set shDest = Sheets("Sheet2") 'for example
  destRow = shDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

  For j = 1 To sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    v = sh.Cells(j, 1).Value
    If InStr(v, "Team") > 0 Then
        If Not rngTeam Is Nothing Then rngTeam.Value = Replace(v, "Team ", "") '<< set for already-copied rows
        Set rngTeam = Nothing 'reset the range
    Else
        shDest.Cells(destRow, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value = sh.Cells(j, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value
        'add to the range to populate next time we hit a "Team"
        If rngTeam Is Nothing Then
            Set rngTeam = shDest.Cells(destRow, 4)
        Else
            Set rngTeam = Application.Union(shDest.Cells(destRow, 4), rngTeam)
        End If
        destRow = destRow + 1
    End If

  Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you very much. Could you please explain the If Not statements?

Comment: Same as "If rngTeam is not Nothing"  - ie. rngTeam has been assigned a value which points to a range.  `rngTeam` is `Nothing` (an unassigned object variable) until you Set it to something.